# no reply from Teredo server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ipv6, teredo

I am trying to implement miredo tunneling on my Ubuntu machine. I setup everything. But I am not getting the teredo interface. When I am checking the miredo service status:

```
$ systemctl status miredo.service
● miredo.service - Teredo IPv6 tunneling
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/miredo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-04-25 10:42:43 IST; 14s ago
  Process: 5067 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/miredo-checkconf -f /etc/miredo/miredo.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5069 (miredo)
   CGroup: /system.slice/miredo.service
           ├─5069 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           ├─5071 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           └─5072 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/miredo/miredo-privproc 9

Apr 25 10:42:43 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 systemd[1]: Starting Teredo IPv6 tunneling...
Apr 25 10:42:43 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 systemd[1]: Started Teredo IPv6 tunnelserver
ing.
Apr 25 10:42:43 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[5069]: Starting...
Apr 25 10:42:43 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[5069]: miredo[5069]: Starting...
Apr 25 10:42:57 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[5071]: No reply from Teredo server
Apr 25 10:42:57 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[5069]: miredo[5071]: No reply from Teredo server
```

I am not getting reply from the teredo server. How we can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by configuring Miredo (via `/etc/miredo/miredo.conf`) to use a Teredo server that actually works – various providers have been *shutting down* their Teredo servers and relays due to increasing availability of native IPv6. I can't seem to find the relevant mailing list posts right now, but Microsoft has been trying to shut down theirs since ~2012.

(There are also repeated claims that Teredo just generally does more harm than good – the relays are often slower than IPv4, the addresses are dynamic so useless for incoming connections.)

One out of remaining Teredo servers is `teredo.remlab.net`, from the Miredo developers.

---

Of course, also make sure your network's firewall allows Teredo traffic – the servers listen on UDP port 3544 for the "binding" messages, while relayed traffic usually uses a somewhat random UDP port number.

Comment: thank you for your reply .this my /etc/miredo/miredo.conf file                  # Please refer to the miredo.conf(5) man page for details.
InterfaceName   teredo

# Pick a Teredo server:
#ServerAddress  teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com
ServerAddress   teredo-debian.remlab.net

# Some firewall/NAT setups require a specific UDP port number:
BindPort        3545
~

Comment: If even the Miredo developers have shut down their Teredo server then it's *really* time to stop using that protocol...

Comment: Teredo has always been tricky. You're better off using a managed tunnel like tunnelbroker.net if you can't get native IPv6

Comment: i tried to create tunnel through tunnelbroker.net .When i am putting the ip address getting this massage                                                                                                IP is not ICMP pingable.Please make sure ICMP is not blocked. If you are blocking ICMP, please allow 66.220.2.74 through your firewall.

Comment: Then just do that. Allow your host/router to receive ping-requests from the internet.